# GetElementById setting to null instead of int

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have this bit of code that just gets an id and assigns it to a variable for some reason notification_id is set to null when it should be an integer from a php for loop

javascript

```
$(".pro_content_notification_remove").live('click', function (e) {

 var notification_id = document.getElementById(this);

 e.preventDefault(); 
 $(this).parent().remove();
```

});

php/html

```
<?php 
    foreach($notification_array as $key => $value){



       echo '<div class="pro_content_notification_ele" id="'.$value.'">
                                    <div class="pro_content_notification_image '.$notification_image_id.'"></div><!--end pro_content_notifications_image-->
                                    <span class="pro_content_notification_text '.$viewed.'">'.$notification_text.'</span>
                                    <div class="pro_content_notification_remove"></div><!--end pro_content_notification_remove-->
                                </div><!--end pro_content_notification_ele-->';
                    }

    ?>
```

I have checked the array and page source and the $value being set in the id of pro_content_notification_ele is definately 1, so why is null being set.

Thanks for the help

Comment: `this` is not a String, and `getElementById` is supposed to return an `HTMLNode`.

Comment: your mixing jquery with 'regular' js in  a strange way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the dom element inside the event handler, so use `this.id` to get the element's ID.

```
$(".pro_content_notification_remove").live('click', function (e) {
    var notification_id = this.id;

    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Note: If you are using jQuery >= 1.7, use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead of .live()

Answer (score 1):

Try using,

```
var notification_id = e.target.id;
```

or

```
var notification_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

or

```
var notification_id = this.id;
```

instead of,

```
var notification_id = document.getElementById(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Insetead of using

```
document.getElementById(this)
```

use

```
$(this).attr('id')
```